# Unable to parse content type of return SOAP request (java)

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to send-retrive message from server by SOAP...

but

```
soapConnection.call( soapMessage, endpoint )
```

returns:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to parse content type: null
```

Hereis my code:

```
    String url = "https://pubcommission.api.cj.com/wsdl/version2/publisherCommissionServiceV2.wsdl";
    String method = "findPublisherCommissionDetails";

    SOAPConnection soapConnection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
    SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

    // Create a message from the message factory.
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

    // creat a SOAP part have populate the envelope
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.setEncodingStyle( SOAPConstants.URI_NS_SOAP_ENCODING );

    // remove all header information from envelope
    envelope.getHeader().detachNode();

    // create a SOAP body
    SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

    Name babelFishRequestName = envelope.createName( method, "ns1", "http://api.cj.com" );
    SOAPBodyElement soapMethod = body.addBodyElement( babelFishRequestName );

    // add elements translationmode and sourcedata to BabelFishRequest
    soapMethod.addChildElement( soapFactory.createElement( "developerKey", "ns1", "http://api.cj.com" ).addTextNode( "nevermind" ) );
    soapMethod.addChildElement( soapFactory.createElement( "originalActionIds", "ns1", "http://api.cj.com" ).addTextNode( "1234567" ) );

    // set the saves into the structure
    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    // output the message
    System.out.println( "\n============= start request msg ==========\n" );
    soapMessage.writeTo( System.out );
    System.out.println( "\n============= end request msg ==========\n" );

    URLEndpoint endpoint = new URLEndpoint(url);
    System.out.println( "\nSending message to URL: " + endpoint.getURL() );

    // now make that call over the SOAP connection
    SOAPMessage reply = soapConnection.call( soapMessage, endpoint );
```

I tried utility 'Membrane' to check result and got the following result (RAW):

```
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Resin/3.1.8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 10:45:47 GMT
X-Cache: MISS from proxy.myserver.com
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxy.myserver.com:3128
Via: 1.0 proxy.myserver.com (squid/3.1.18)
Connection: close

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Action id specified does not match your account: 1234567</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: The URL you are using points to the WSDL, try replacing it with the actual web service URL.

Comment: do you men url:  String url = "h ttps://pubcommission.api.cj.com" ?

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my first comment. Can't help you with that error. See my approach using JAX-WS below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about that error. If using JAX-WS API is an option for you, this is the way to go:

Use wsimport tool to generate client objects:

```
wsimport.bat -keep -d "\ProjectDir\src" https://pubcommission.api.cj.com/wsdl/version2/publisherCommissionServiceV2.wsdl
```

This will generate everything you need to call the web service:

```
com.cj.api
com.cj.domain.transaction
com.cj.service.transaction
```

In the `api` package you find the service and port objects, the latter allows you to access the web service methods:

```
PublisherCommissionServiceV2 service = new PublisherCommissionServiceV2();
PublisherCommissionServiceV2PortType port = service.getPublisherCommissionServiceV2HttpPort();
port.findPublisherCommissionDetails("key", "id");
```

This will give you a nice `not authenticated: key` message from the web service.

Comment: cool!! Thanks ... The main negative of it is a lot-lot of classes :(

Comment: That's true. Perhaps you might want to give the [Dispatch API](http://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-ea3/docs/dispatch.html) a look.